# laravel on windows cant find views

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i installed laravel 4.2 on my windows pc and get error that view cannot by foundet

```
InvalidArgumentException
View [layout.index] not found.
```

my controller content

```
protected $layout = 'layout.index';

public function home()
{
    return $this->layout->content = View::make('content_index.home');
}
```

but realy file exists 'views/layout/index.blade.php'
its kinda bug or something ?

Answer (score 0):

The folder is actually /layouts, so your view should be located at :

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.index';
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem is start after I run this on local:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

after that I run this in vagrant and solve problem.

open ssh

```
php artisan config:cache
```